# Postgresql function as trigger before deleting a row from t_suppliers

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.t_products
(
    product_id integer NOT NULL,
    product_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    supplier_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT t_products_pkey PRIMARY KEY (product_id);   

CREATE TABLE public.t_suppliers

    (
        supplier_id integer NOT NULL,
        supplier_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT t_suppliers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id)
    );
```

I would like to know, how to write a function, that will not allow me to delete a record from t_supplier if I use this supplier_id in t_products. I know, I can do this by foreign key but I want to learn how to write a function.
What should be in function body?

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleting_supplier
   BEFORE DELETE ON t_suppliers FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE is_del_possible();
```

Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_del_possible() RETURNS trigger AS
$$BEGIN
   ???
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: This are the same tables

Comment: I'm sorry, i fixed just the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function needs only to validate that the `supplier_id` *does not exist* in the `products` table. The easiest way for this is the [exists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html) expression. While the documentation states a subquery, plpgsql allows it following `if`. So

```
create or replace function is_del_possible() 
  returns trigger 
  language plpgsql 
as $$
begin
    if exists (select null 
                 from t_products 
                where supplier_id = old.supplier_id 
              ) 
    then 
        raise exception E'Cannot delete supplier_id %.\nIt is referenced in Products table', to_char(old.supplier_id,'999999999'; 
    end if ; 

   return old;
end; 
$$;
```